# Geometry Nodes: Array around center point

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am quite new to geo nodes. I want to Array my geometry around a center point but what ever I am using as input in a secound Instance on Points Node, I cant get the result I am looking for. Can you help please?

Thank you

[image: Thats what I want to do]
[image: What I did so far]
Ive added another Instance on Points Node after the first one and used my set geometry as instance input but I need the input for the points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use this node setup here:

[image]

result:

[image]

Two things are important for the instance on points node:

1. the points -> these are the positions on which your "instance" is placed on
2. the pivot point of your instance -> because the pivot points of your instance will be placed on these "points" of 1) so you have to make sure that the pivot point is on the right place, in your case it has to be on one end of your curve. That's what i achieved with the transform geometry nodes before plugging the bezier segment into the instance.

In the gif i show you what happens, if i change the value of the transform geometry node (and by this changing the pivot point of the bezier segment).

I used a mesh line without an offset as points so all points are on the same position. I have to idea why you use a spiral, but by this every point where your instance is placed on is on another position.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much the same as what Chris does, but using a spiral to create the repeated curve:

[image]

Could be slightly condensed with a map range:

[image]